# How to know which email the client replied to

Tags: node.js, mailgun, adonis.js, cloudmailin

I am using mailgun features to send email to clients using Adonis. I am sending two types of emails:

1. Welcome Email - When the user signs up to my website.
2. Orders Email - When the user orders an item.

   Now when someone replies to the mail(welcome or orders mail), I am receiving that that reply in my backend and storing it.

   My doubt is **how to i know if the client replied to welcome email or orders email?**

Comment: 2 (possible) solutions: 1) In emails there is in the headers a "messge id" either compare the message id or set a custom header with your own id to identify replys. 2) Set a id/number in the subect, with a fromat like `[xxxxxx] Welcome to xyz`  and parse the subject.

Comment: Hi, Can you please help me out in figuring out how do I add custom headers or where?

Comment: I dont know if its possible. Never worked with mailgon/adonis.js/cloudmailin. If its not possible to add/read the header fields, then you have to work with the subject approch. Seems like you can set custom headers with the mailgun package on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun#example i have to few informations to help you.

Comment: Read the docs: https://docs.cloudmailin.com/http_post_formats/json_normalized/#headers Im sure get very quickly to a possible solution. It seems every provider has what you need to achive this via custom headers. Read how a email is strutured (very similar to a html request/response)

Comment: okay, I'll go through this thank you :)